# Creating an Orchard theme

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create an Orchard theme and not sure if I'm doing the correct thing regarding how to it "correctly" in Orchard.

I have set my Layout.html as my Master Page per se, where I have a zone called Content, then I have create a page called Content-Page.html, now inside there, I want different shape's data in different order e.g.

```
<h1>onePart.Name</h1>
<p>Hi this is an example twoPart.Data and onePart.Data </p>
```

How do I intersperse this using Shapes? Do I access the field's directly, use a wrapper? Currently I'm doing this.

```
var onePart= Model.ContentItem.CustomPart;
```

This allows me to put the data where it needs to be, I've found may of the articles, but it seems to show if your Shapes has all the data it needs, my issue is I don't really want a theme to have a dependency on a Module.

Comment: why would you need a reference to do that? This is dynamic access, so it is resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to make use of the `placement.info` file to position your widgets. For finding out which shape/widget you're looking at and how to override it you can install the **[Designer tools module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools)**.

I suggest you also take a look, by downloading, some of the templates from the **[theme gallery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes)** and inspect these. I learned quite a lot from these myself.